# Is my proof correct? (group theory, Lagrange)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

$G$ is a finite group.

Prove, that $\exists k\in G:k\neq 1_G, k^2=1_G \iff |G|$ is even.

**My proof**

**1)** $\Rightarrow$:

$\exists k\in G: k^2 = 1_G\Rightarrow \exists G'\leq G$ s.t. $ G'=\{1_G,k\}$, then $|G'|=2$

Using Lagrange Theorem:

$|G'|$ divides $|G|\Rightarrow |G|$ is even.

**2)** $\Leftarrow$:

$|G|=2n\Rightarrow |G|\geq 2$ and $|G|=2n\Rightarrow\exists G'\leq G$ with $|G'|=2\Rightarrow\{1_G=1_{G'}, k\}= G'$ and $k=k^{-1}\Rightarrow |k|=2$

$\blacksquare$

Could you please review my proof? I'm currently learning how to write proofs using as few words as possible, so could you also check if the syntax is correct?

Comment: Proof looks right. I think it is more clear to say $G'=\{1,k\}$ than $\{1_G=1_{G'},k\}\in G'$ as the latter only says $\{1,k\}$ is a subset of $G'$.

Comment: $\{1_G,k\}$ is a *subset* $G'$ (not an element, so $\in$ is wrong). What allows you to draw the conclusion after the second $\Rightarrow$ in 2)?? You need the [theorem of Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) there.

Comment: @drhab: Well, since $G$ is a group it must have at least one element (identity). In this situation it is also even, so it must have at least two elements. In this case there is a subgroup $G'$ which consists only of the identity and one self-inverse element, which would be k.

Comment: Yes, $G$ has at least $2$ elements, but that would also be the case if $|G|=3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the reverse implication I think you were trying to express this:-
If for all the elements $x\neq e$ in $G$, $x\neq x^{-1}$ then including identity total number of elements in $G$ is odd, which is not the case, so there must exist a non-identity element in $G$ which is its own inverse.

Comment: I have my doubts whether the OP was trying to express this. If it was indeed his intention then he did not prove it properly. Nevertheless this is a nice way of proving the theorem of Cauchy in special case $p=2$.

Comment: Well you can see his (first) comment in the answer by @skyking :D. By the way what does OP mean?

Comment: I don't know what OP stands for. It refers to the person who asked the question. After seeing a lot of times on this site I made it a part of my vocabulary.

Comment: @drhab: I believe it means Original Poster. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're a little bit sloppy at the second part of the proof. Note that the premise is that $|G|$ is even (and $G$ is finite). The existence of $k$ is not part of the premise, but you seem to use it without motivation.

Then of course formally ${1_G=1_{G'}, k}$ is probably not a member of $G'$, but possibly a subset of it.

The second part could for example be proven by noting that with $|G|\le2$ we have a non-identity element (generating a subgroup) that has either even or odd order. If it's even you can easily find the $k$ by taking the middle element. If it's odd you can use cosets to find a proper sub group $G'$ with $|G'|$ being even and repeat.

Comment: But if $k$ wouldn't exist, the number of elements of the group couldn't be even.

Comment: @de_dust Agreed that there is an element that is not the identity, but that doesn't make it have the properties of the $k$ mentioned in the claim. Therefore it's not that clear that $k$ exists - in the sence it being the $k$ mentioned in the claim.

Answer (score 2):

The implication in **2**) $\Leftarrow$:  $|G|\geq2\Rightarrow\cdots$ is incorrect.

If e.g. $|G|=3>2$ then no $k\in G$ exists with $k\neq1_G$ and $k^2=1_G$.

The [theorem of Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) can be applied here:

If $p$ is a prime that divides the order of $G$ then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.

Comment: But $|G|$ can't equal $3$ because $|G|$ is even . That's the point.

Comment: The premise is that |G| is even and bigger or equal then 2.

Comment: You make your conclusion on base of $|G|\geq2$ and this condition is satisfied if $|G|=3$. Then your premisse should be $|G|$ is even **and** $|G|\geq2$. Secondly: also under this correct premisse you need argumentation to prove the existence of some $k$ having order $2$. That argumentation is given by Cauchy. You cannot just assume that such $k$ exists. That is not a proof.

Comment: You were right about the premise. It was defined imprecisely and I fixed it. However, I cannot understand what's wrong with my $k$. I didn't just assume that it exists. Its existence is the direct implication of the premise. If $k$ hadn't existed, then $|G|$ would be odd. Can you give an example of a group which has an even cardinality but no self-inverse elements besides the identity element?

Comment: No, I cannot give an example of such group, since they do not exist. If $2$ divides the order of $G$ then there is an element $k$ that has order $2$. But this fact needs a proof on its own and I cannot find it as a part of your proof. Essential is that $2$ is a prime. If e.g. $4$ divides the order of $G$ then as counterexample there is the $4$-group of Klein that has no elements with order $4$. Is @2015 correct in his assumption about what you were trying to express? His answer contains a real proof and I could really not find such a thing as a part of your proof.